# Delete old versions of lambda functions uploaded through CloudFormation package command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am using [`aws cloudformation package`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudformation/package.html) to automatically package and upload Lambda function code to an S3 bucket.

When I upload a new version of the Lambda function, previous objects remain in the S3 bucket. Is there any way to automatically remove "old" versions when uploading a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly there is no such way with just `aws cloudformation package` command. You would have to chain with other command to delete (`aws s3api delete-object`) the previous version yourself.